# About the convenient rewriting of formulas of sequences?

Tags: calculus, analysis

I'm reading Courant's Introduction to Calculus and Analysis. In the introduction, he shows some examples of limits of sequences, the sequence in question is:

$$a_n=\frac{n^2-1}{n^2+n+1}$$

Then he rewrites it as:

$$a_n=1-\frac{n+2}{n^2+n+1}$$

And he argues that this helps to see that the limit of $a_n$ is $1$. I'm not really acquainted with this idea of rewriting it to see that the sequence converges. I could try some guesses and rewrite it in other ways, but I believe there might be some explanation of a general method of rewriting it. Is there such a thing?

I've had classes about it, but the lecturer just used to rewrite it without some explanation of this rewriting technique.

Comment: He rewrote it by dividing the top by the bottom (using long division), but Kaster's way of rewriting it is better and easier.

Answer (score 3):

Another way (which is pretty much the same really) is to divide everything by $n^2$, so
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {n^2-1}{n^2+n+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {1 - \frac 1{n^2}}{1 + \frac 1n + \frac 1{n^2}} = \frac {1 - \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1{n^2}}{1 + \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty }\frac 1n + \lim_{n \to \infty }\frac 1{n^2}} = 1
$$

Answer (score 1):

In general,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty }\frac{\sum_{k=1}^p a_in^i}{\sum_{k=1}^m a_in^i}=\lim_{n\to\infty }\frac{a_p n^p}{a_mn^m}$$

It's easy to prove it, I let you do it :-)

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
a_n&=\frac{n^2-1}{n^2+n+1}\\
&=\frac{n^2+n+1-n-2}{n^2+n+1}\\
&=1-\frac{n+2}{n^2+n+1}\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1-\frac{n+2}{n^2+n+1}\right)\\
&=1-\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{n+2}{n^2+n+1}\right)\\
&=1-\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac n{n^2}\\
&=1-\cancelto{0}{\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac 1{n}}\\
&=1\qquad \blacksquare\end{align}$$